# jQuery ajax load() file not working in localhost - (w3scools.com jQuery AJAX sample tutorial)

Tags: jquery

can't get this tutorial working in localhost:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax1

my jquery.js file has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    // AJAX //
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("div").load('ajax.txt');
    });
});
```

and the ajax.txt file is in the same folder, but no file is loaded.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Found an answer! With a code above your file ajax.txt should be in root folder. Otherwise change following line:
$("div").load('ajax.txt');
to:
$("div").load('assets/js/ajax.txt');
or whatever folder tree you have, starting from site root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load() function starts looking for a file in a root directory not in the same as the ajax file is. So with a code above your file ajax.txt should be in root folder. Otherwise change following line:

```
$("div").load('ajax.txt');
```

to:

```
$("div").load('assets/js/ajax.txt');
```

or whatever folder tree you have, starting from site root folder!