# Having problems with load() function

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following is part of my site, just removed some code that i know is not necessary fro the question;

```
<div id="Container">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id='TopNav'>
<ul>
  <li> <a href=''>Home</a></li>
  <li><a  href ='' id='bt1'>Contact EHC</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Student Portal</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Lecturer Portal</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>How To Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Student Union</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>News</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Tutorials</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Log In</a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href=''>Graduation</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- topNav closes here -->

<div id="Content"></div>
<!-- Content div ends here -->

<div id="Footer"></div>
</div> <!-- conatiner closes here-->
```

The css for #content is the following:

```
#Content {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 800px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
background-color: #F5FDFE;
text-indent: 0px;
text-align: justify;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

My jQuery function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#bt1').click(function() {
       $('#content').load('other.html');
   });

});
```

When I try to use the jQuery function above it does not work, the #content div just stays blank when I click on "Contact EHC". The console does not show any errors, I am using WAMP as my testing server. Is there anything wrong with my code that can prevent the jQuery function from working?  a simple code like alert('Hello'); works just fine if I include it in there. I apologize if the problem is obvious, i am teaching myself web development, it is for my final year project at college.

Comment: can you check in console whether the AJAX call works out correctly? we don't know the details of your localhost environment, so maybe there's no data coming from '/other.html' ??

Comment: Also avoid using .load since its deprecated
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @Frisbetarian, OP is using http://api.jquery.com/load/ which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research i discovered that i was forgetting to include some code that will prevent the link from being followed. The following code worked for me just fine. Thank you or your answers.

```
$('#bt1').click(function() {
$('#content').load('other.html');
return false; <----------- This is the code i was missing out
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $("#content").html('<object data="http://other.html/">');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe a path problem, but you would have a 404 error : [jQuery ajax load() file not working in localhost - (w3scools.com jQuery AJAX sample tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639723/jquery-ajax-load-file-not-working-in-localhost-w3scools-com-jquery-ajax-sam).
2. Are you sure to use your local server? http: // localhost? load () function does not work in file: //
3. If you are using Google Chrome browser take a look in the dev tools "Network" tab, to be sure the ajax call works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bt1').click(function() {
                $("#content").load('/jquery/result.html');
            });
        });
    </script>
```